# Allow seeing the editing list from review queues (Triage)

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, edits, triage

So I recently got the option to enter review queues. And I've stumbled upon the the following scenario in the `Triage queue`:

- First reviewer said `Unsalvageable`
- Someone said `Looks OK`
- Someone else said `Looks OK`
- I said the question `Looks OK`

And then the question was approved as `OK`.

So to summarize someone said it was unsalvageable and then we said it was OK.

I do not have access to the editing list but I guess that there was some editing going around between these reviews.

I think in these cases (when there was an edit) the reviewers should have access to the editing list (for padding and or accepted editing), in order to judge better the quality of the question and its ability to improve.
Also I do not know how the system works: the questions from suggested edits queue goes to triage afterwards?

By editing list I mean this editing system you see (like in github) on your own questions after an edit by someone else.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain? This is my first question on meta.

Comment: A downvote on meta for a feature request generally means the voter disagrees with the request (i.e., thinks it shouldn't be implemented or is not needed).

Comment: Unsalvageable is supposed to mean that nobody *but the asker* is able to edit it to salvage it, and until then, isn't worth keeping.  It doesn't mean, "Eh, it sucks, but somebody can edit it to improve it.  Won't be me, though."

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Oh ok.. So should I close the question? How does this affect my reputation?

Comment: @fbueckert Yes I understand that, I just think that you can conclude the quality from previous editing.

Comment: @Yonlif on Meta voting doesn't affect your reputation. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Triage is a "quick and dirty" queue to quickly weed out the absolute junk that is beyond hope. Don't worry about whether or not it may be edited while you are there or later. Make a decision on what you see in front of you and move on.